# How to import a database (or Schema) using impdp command in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, import, impdp

I've not worked in Oracle database anytime. Everything I've done in databases is using only MySql. I got a .dpdmp file which I need to import it into Oracle database.

I tried with the example provided in this link, but not a single statement is executed. Totally it completes with 208 error

http://gerardnico.com/wiki/database/oracle/oracle_db_datapump

```
impdp system/root DIRECTORY=data_dump_dir DUMPFILE=MYDUMPFILE.DPDMP
```

If I look at the log files, I assume this is the root cause of the problem

```
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-39083: Object type USER:"MYUSER" failed to create with error:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
```

Since the user creation failed, so every statements that is executed after this also resulted in error. The dump file is created in Oracle 10G where my Oracle is 12c. Is this due to the version conflict?

Comment: Have you set a database name variable? If not it seems you are connecting to the container db (12c feature). Try to put the database name in the login script: impdp system/root@mydb etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please create the user "MYUSER" and then try to import with additional parameters like

```
remap_talbespace=old_tbsp:new_tbsp
```

This will import the data into your new tablespace